# Где взять последние заголовки OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

На MinGW в папке с инклудами есть файлы gl.h и др., но в именах макросов `GL_VERSION_1_3` максимальная версия, как я понимаю, но мне нужны версии больше 3+.

P.S. Гуглить умею, но хотелось бы пользоваться "не подделку"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, под Windows все пользуются этим самым древним gl.h на пару с [glext.h](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/glext.h), получают все функции через механизм расширений (запрос указателя на функцию через wglGetProcAddress). Вроде бы даже для OpenGL 3 - 4 не существует обновленных заголовков. Разве что в составе SDK от вендора видеокарт.

Да, неудобно, но расширения полностью предоставляют функционал последних поддерживаемых видеокартой версий OpenGL, и дёргать их (на заморачиваясь с wglGetProcAdress и объявлением переменных) можно с помощью общепринятой библиотеки GLEW.